# Yolov3 COCO detection Metrics

Tags: detection, metrics

I am training YoloV3 using Darknet with this repository : https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet . When testing, I obtain the mAP value as well as Precision, Recall, and F1 Score for threshold 0.25. However I would like to obtain the COCO detection evaluation metrics as stated in this page: http://cocodataset.org/#detection-eval, namely these values,  AP at IoU=.50:.05:.95, AP at IoU=.50 (PASCAL VOC metric), AP at IoU=.75   and AP Across Scales. Any help will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Which command do you use to test it?